# Share PivotCache for PivotTables built with data model

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am just cleaning up my workbook and I have used the following code to consolidate my PivotCaches (I had around 200 prior to the cleaning).

```
Sub changeCache()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim first As Boolean
On Error Resume Next

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

            If first = False Then
                Set pc = pt.PivotCache
                first = True
            End If 

            pt.CacheIndex = pc.Index

        Next pt
    Next ws

End Sub
```

This has reduced my PivotCache count to 33.

```
Sub CountCaches()
  MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
End Sub
```

The reason it is 33 and not 1 is because I have 32 PivotTables that are built with the **Data Model**.

**My question is:** Does anyone know how to change PivotTables built with the Data Model to all use the same PivotCache?

**EDIT**

**My secondary question is:** Do multiple pivot tables all built on a data model

a) reference a single data model; or

b) each have their own model and therefore 'bloat' the Excel file

**EDIT2**

On further exploration, it appears that the data model **is** shared for pivot tables that reference the same data. This can be seen in 'Connections' (found under the 'Data' tab in the ribbon). In theory, this shouldn't 'bloat' the file even though the code `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count` counts each pivot table that shares a connection and falsely(?) indicates multiple caches.

I will however leave the bounty open in case someone can provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: Check the information on this page. I have not tested to see if the cache is built the same way but it might get you closer to an answer.

http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/cut-the-size-of-your-pivot-table-workbooks-in-half/

Comment: Thanks for the link but no luck

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you just have to set each pc to the first one. So, the first pass, give the pc some other name such as pcfirst, then For each remaining cache, set pc=pcfirst. Some source information here http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html and here http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/380933-set-multiple-pivot-cache-read-one-cache.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, but unfortunately they don't address the question directly. They contain some great information on cleaning up pivot caches, but it seems that pivot tables built with the data model (i.e. checking the box 'Add this data to the Data Model' when you create the pivot), are not constructed around a pivot cache

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet really used to Data Model and I can't provide doubtless explainations about this.

But I used that code to clean one of the reporting system I was working on, that might help you to get less PivotCaches :

```
Sub Caches_Matches()
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, _
    Pt1 As PivotTable, _
    Ws2 As Worksheet, _
    Pt2 As PivotTable, _
    PcNb As Integer

PcNb = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
MsgBox "PivotCaches.Count = " & PcNb, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Before update"

On Error Resume Next

    For Each Ws1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Pt1 In Ws1.PivotTables
            'fix one pt, loop all of them and set same cache if same source
            For Each Ws2 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                For Each Pt2 In Ws2.PivotTables
                    If Pt1.SourceData <> Pt2.SourceData Or Pt1.PivotCache = Pt2.PivotCache Or Pt1.Name = Pt2.Name Then
                    Else
                        Pt2.CacheIndex = Pt1.PivotCache.Index
                    End If
                Next Pt2
            Next Ws2
        Next Pt1
    Next Ws1

MsgBox "PivotCaches.Count = " & ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count & Chr(10) & _
        "Before update = " & PcNb, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "After update"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately your code produces the same result to that of my code posted in the original question. Multiple caches are still being reported for pivot tables built with the data model.

Comment: I hoped, but I didn't find much about the subject to work with, hope you'll find a way!

Comment: Thanks bud! From the research I did it looks like even though ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count reports multiple caches for the tables built with data models, those caches are essentially empty and do not bloat the file (which was my main concern).

Comment: Thx for info, that may be useful to me someday!